# window height using jquery in android returns too big number

Tags: android, jquery, webview

i am using jquery mobile on android in a webview. i am using Samsung Galaxy mini with 240x320 screen resolution. wowever, when i use $(window).height() function it returns 401 (the webview takes the maximum amount of screen size minus the notification bar). hoe can it return even more than the screen size?

Comment: Just curious if you put an image with a fixed height of 320px, does it take up the whole screen as you would expect?

Comment: actually it is just a div page that contains some more sub divs.